Is it safe and effective to run two window air conditioners in the same opening?
Solved - I will take yours and other's advice about improving insulation. I'll use the unit I have now until the cooler months around October and over the winter add better insulation in the attic above the garage over time in the winter.

My problem is the AC in my garage is not enough during these summer months (3 months a year is only when my garage AC doesn't keep up). I am currently at the most power BTU window unit but it is not enough. I can dedicate about $300 to this project and efficient use of time. Ordering and installing a 2nd unit is about 1 hour of effort. I am not overly concerned with electricity costs because this only needs to provide cooling for 2-3 hours a few days a week for a few months of the year.
Would it be unsafe to have both units installed atop each other on different GFCI grounded circuits in one of those panels I mentioned above? Is 18 inches of space between top and bottom sufficient? I would put a piece of metal between them to help with cooling and dripping.
Here are my hurdles: I can not improve insulation to achieve my goals.  I do not have 240v in my garage and I don't have the means to install it. I can't install a bigger unit because it requires 240v.
My proposed solution is to run a 2nd AC unit on a separate circuit breaker to achieve cooling.
Current Setup is a 120v LG Window Ac unit that I can turn on from my phone. It is in my garage. My garage was enclosed by previous owner to be a screen room. Where there would be double garage doors there is instead framed aluminum and screen. I put foam board where the screen is to enclose and sealed gaps with duct-tape. Enclosing it by framing and drywall would require permits and probably a contractor. When it is about 95 degrees and 60% humidity the AC may get me to 85 or 87 degrees which is too high.
Things I've tried.
Evaporative cooling fans
Traditional Fans
If this were a needed permanent fix I'd insulate the ceiling of my garage, but that requires me cleaning out my attic, removing the plywood atop and putting down insulation. The downside of this is that it may not cool enough because I'd still be battling the walls that just have foam board on them. I am very confident that a 2nd window unit would get me another 6 or 7 degrees based on how the current one is performing.

EDITED - Do you mean the rafters or the horizontal joists that are between the ceiling and my attic floor?   --->
Attic insulation is like 1/4 of an inch above the garage. Above the home it is good. There is no ventilation other than 2 ridge cap vents, each about 30 feet long. Although the foam insulation on the ceiling would work it would look even more odd than 2 stacked units. I do agree it would work but its cumbersome with storage. From a safety point of view I can't see any obvious issues - do you?

You'll spend more on electricity in the first summer of use than you would spend on adding some insulation so that that one AC is sufficient.

You might only use the garage a few hours, but the AC units need time to cool down the whole building, so add double to the time at least, so instead of 3 you are looking at 6 hours.

Bite the bullet and insulate.  What exactly do you mean by foam board?  Got pics?

@DrMoishePippik I will take yours and other's advice about improving insulation. I'll use the unit I have now until the cooler months around October and over the winter add better insulation in the attic above the garage over time in the winter.
Thanks.

To answer the question as posed, here are the primary concerns:

Heat could transfer between units. The dissipating heat from one compressor unit could affect the other unit. This is especially true with heat rising from the lower unit to the upper. This could impact performance and longevity.

Heated intake air could reduce operational efficiency. If the intake air is warmer it can't extract as much heat from the coils. This could result in longer cycle duration to achieve the same cooling.


Other thoughts (migrated from comments):
Battling the sun like this seems foolish. You'd probably accomplish your goal by simply hanging reflective sheet foam under the ceiling joists. Isolation from the roasting roof is key--your walls are probably fine. Consider long-term cost and environmental impact.
